# How to deserialize a JSON array to a List using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Tags: c#, list, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON file but for some reason, I just can't seem to get it to work. Is this the correct way to deserialize a JSON array to a list.

This is the JSON Data I would like to deserialize and put into the coursework object

```py
{ 
   "assignments":[ 
      { 
         "categoryname":"Exams",
         "description":"Test covers C#, classes and other topics",
         "name":"Exam 1"
      },
      { 
         "categoryname":"Exams",
         "description":"Test covers collections and other topics",
         "name":"Exam 2"
      },
```

Deserialization Method I am using

```py
            List<T> ReadJsonFile1<T>(List<T> obj)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Json File Name: ");
                string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
                FileStream reader = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                DataContractJsonSerializer deser;
                deser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));

                obj = (List<T>)deser.ReadObject(reader);

                reader.Close();
                return obj;
            }
```

Code I execute in Main

```py
            CourseWork cw = new CourseWork();

            cw.Assignment = ReadJsonFile1<Assignment>(cw.Assignment);
```

CourseWork Class

```py
public class CourseWork
    {
        private List<Assignment> assignments;

        [DataMember(Name = "assignmentname")]
        public List<Assignment> Assignment
        {
            get { return assignments; }
            set { assignments = value; }
        }

        public CourseWork()
        {
            assignments = new List<Assignment>();
        }
```

Assignment Class

```py
        private string name;
        private string description;
        private string categoryName;

        //DataContract
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        //DataContract
        [DataMember(Name = "description")]
        public string Description 
        {
            get { return description; }
            set { description = value; }
        }

        //DataContract
        [DataMember(Name = "categoryname")]
        public string CategoryName
        {
            get { return categoryName; }
            set { categoryName = value; }
        }

        public Assignment()
        {
            name = "defaut";
            description = "defaut";
            categoryName = "defaut";
        }
```

Comment: Btw. You could make your properties `public string Name { get; set; }`?

Comment: Yes, I think I can but other parts of the project I have been setting the get/set like I have shown so I don't feel like switching now. Already tried switching and testing it with auto-implementation and nothing new happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did not take into consideration is that CourseWork is not a list, it just has lists inside it as private member variables. To fix my problem I had to change my `List<T> ReadJsonFile1<T>(List<T> obj)` function back to what I had it earlier in the project `T ReadJsonFile1<T>(T obj)` Basically just taking all the Lists out and making them normal type of T. I also needed to add DataContract Names to ALL my classes. My DataMembers were fine but since this is a Json Array I needed to add the DataContract above every class like in the **Assignment** class and also the CourseWork Class, just need to make sure you give your DataContract the correct name.

**SOLUTION**

```py
List<T> ReadJsonFile1<T>(List<T> obj)
```

```py
 [DataContract(Name = "coursename")]
  public class CourseWork
  {
```

```py
[DataContract(Name = "assignments")]
    public class Assignment
     {
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1

I don't know this deserialiser well but

```
deser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
```

Should likely be something like

```
deser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CourseWork));
```

## 2

```
  [DataMember(Name = "assignmentname")]
        public List<Assignment> Assignment
```

quite likely should be

```
  [DataMember(Name = "assignments")]
        public List<Assignment> Assignment
        {
```

Comment: Your where kinda right, but there was a little more missing then just that. My solution shows exactly what I needed to add. But yes I needed to make `deser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));` Into this `deser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));` And adjust other parts in the function to just take in T, and I did need to fix Datamembers and DataContracts, Thank you.
`